# How to copy directories and files in the following scenario?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a source folder that contains a few directories and some files. It may look something like this:

```
custom app 1 (directory)
custom app 2 (directory)
file1
file2
file3
```

The user will select an app and it should copy everything for the app except what is not needed, so for example, if the user selected app 1, the target folder should contain:

```
images (this images directory is from custom app 1 in the source folder)
file1
file2
file3
```

Notice above, how I extracted only the contents of custom app 1, which was a folder called images in this case and copied it to the target folder and disregarded custom app 2.

What is the best way to accomplish the above?

Comment: do you mean that, the folder that the user selects should be copied, and not anything else..?

Comment: I will have an xml file that will contain a list of folders and files to exclude

Comment: I think that information would be pretty crucial to have in the question..

Comment: Well, you want to do a top down recursive iteration of the source folder, checking each file against your various exclusion patterns. There is some opportunity for optimization if certain branches of recursion should be completely excluded.